# RichText and linked components

Tags: dd4t

I have a richtext with linked component inside. Also, I have added LinkLevel=9 for my page template and component template. This link is in the scope of these levels.

What do you think is the best way to be resolved this component because it is not serialized and sent with the content of the page?
I use Tridion2011sp1, and DD4T 1.25.

I am implementing the next scenario: when I parse the rich text and if I find a linked component then I request the broker for that component.

Maybe there is better and more elegant way of doing that.

Comment: What do you really want to have - You have a linked component in the RTF and you want the corresponding page link to get resolved at run time or you need the content of the linked component at the run time to manipulate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, LinkLevel 9 is way too high. This may make publishing extremely slow in a production situation! It is also not necessary if you want to resolve component links as hyperlinks to another page (as I suspect you are trying to do). I would set it back to 1 or 2.

Second, parsing links in rich text is included in the latest DD4T release (1.30). It can be downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/downloads/list.

If you don't want to upgrade, I suggest you download the latest source code and copy the class DD4T.Mvc.Html.RichTextHelper to your own project.

Comment: I have another question related with the rich text. Whether, this 1.3 version of DD4T solves the problem when we create a component template for a component(with richtext field), and we publish it on the broker then all linked components in the richtext to be published on the broker too?
Or maybe I missed to add a needed building blog in my component template?

Comment: @BorisT. could you post this as a separate question please?